# What's going on when I assign to "." in dplyr's do() function?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Consider the following table:

```
df <- as.tbl(data.frame(grp=c("a","b","c","d","e"), a=1:5, b=6:10))
```

Let's say I want to add a column to the table that is the product of columns a and b.

I could just do `df$product <- df$a * df$b`. If I want to use `do()` the following works:

```
df %>% group_by(grp) %>% do({
  d <- .
  d$product <- d$a * d$b
  d #expression returns the data frame, d
})

#result is as expected
     grp     a     b product
  <fctr> <int> <int>   <int>
1      a     1     6       6
2      b     2     7      14
3      c     3     8      24
4      d     4     9      36
5      e     5    10      50
```

But it does not work as expected when I assign to `.`:

```
df %>% group_by(grp) %>% do({
  .$product <- .$a * .$b
  .
})

#The output only includes data from row 1 (grp==a) of the input
     grp     a     b product
  <fctr> <int> <int>   <int>
1      a     1     6       6
2      a     1     6       6
3      a     1     6       6
4      a     1     6       6
5      a     1     6       6
```

Comment: Please expand on how your second effort "does not work". `dplyr` is still very much version < 1 and so we need more information on how it "does not work" for you. Errors? Wrong numbers? Computer explodes?

Comment: The simplest answer is “you cannot assign to `.`” but that’s of course quite unsatisfactory.

Comment: @KonradRudolph both examples work fine if you don't have the group_by, so it seems that under some circumstances you can assign to ".", or at least you can get away with it. But I'd agree, "." is special and don't play with it. Ever.

Comment: @Spacedman Yeah, assignment to `.` is simply undefined behaviour. Literally, since it’s quite undocumented.

Comment: I'm using dplyr version 0.7.1, R version 3.4.0, Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: I think this should be reported as a bug.

Comment: @ChiPak Fyi, SO chat rooms are probably a better venue for comments that don't fit in the comment box (like your deleted answer below).

Comment: @Frank Thanks, I'll look into it. Definitely a better idea than posting a non-answer Answer

Comment: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2970